# transformClassesWithDesugar build error after updating to AS 3.0 Canary 6

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I updated to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 6 and am now getting following error (had been on Canary 5).  I've searched for people seeing similar issues but no luck so far.  Anyone else seeing anything like this?  (note fwiw that project includes some Kotlin code)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:295)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:173)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:75)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:77)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:137)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:368)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:297)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:251)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:543)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForCustomDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-auth-11.0.1.aar/91f94c8cb7e863a526130efb6853f44d/jars/classes.jar --output /Users/jooreill/devroot/github.com/augerlabs/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/custom/debug/74.jar --input /Users/jooreill/devroot/github.com/augerlabs/android/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/customDebug --output /Users/jooreill/devroot/github.com/augerlabs/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/custom/debug/104 --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/devroot/github.com/augerlabs/android/app/libs/Vuforia.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/multidex-1.0.1.aar/68aa367bb1e87f4c04d0e8096afbe360/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rxlifecycle-components-0.6.1.aar/b837126d50eda35a238e7bd86cc1c425/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter-1.0.4.aar/f4c62ec6b68561c4c8f2e0a5ec0d80d9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/exomedia-3.1.1.aar/66adb78bc9c4c7786a58a994c00a5ef8/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/playlistcore-1.1.1.aar/49d1cb56d61981c150fcde68d63144bf/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/PanoramaImageView-1.0.aar/1c32f8cf1813084b859814da32240f8e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/facebook-android-sdk-4.18.0.aar/92ff51227982206289a7eff19a88041a/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/sparkbutton-1.0.0.aar/5487c596f92c0fa9837a90297f6e3855/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/dexter-2.3.1.aar/a4ef168e02436f01282cf4d1d6b39115/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/algoliasearch-android-3.5.aar/198199df4a842a59c23abc3be195b0c3/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-ui-auth-2.0.1.aar/e649eadac02602bd44077d02205a69da/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-26.0.0-beta2.aar/443b130b797612ac88bab855035932ec/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.0.0-beta2.aar/85f6ae44a239c549b0042f86bb3779c9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0-beta2.aar/db8b12f40c909a751a361300ace3e62c/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/cardview-v7-26.0.0-beta2.aar/18111878d92e05ebcf30f4ffebc5865a/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/palette-v7-26.0.0-beta2.aar/26eee6a40e9f2e65d1ebcd11de343be2/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/percent-26.0.0-beta2.aar/f3770d7d087221317999746fbad190c6/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v13-26.0.0-beta2.aar/00f89973d57b4060ff2f1d93e208ccfe/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rxlifecycle-0.6.1.aar/10994c956dc569d4685b2653d4d5fae3/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.3.0/43e4ac24adc40a24c51b2d2a71a2483ef1b0ce9a/adapter-rxjava-2.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rxbinding-0.4.0.aar/d267b21156fab2ff1e4b01d8be62cc26/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/rxandroid-1.1.0.aar/a051ff597c8879651794b4cdbc0288c4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.3.0/af000bec2036a2a9d07197c4b03b8966bfc60b03/rxjava-1.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/keen-client-api-android-5.0.0.aar/3bce97b05132f7845a1ab1f10afcb558/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.keen/keen-client-java-core/5.0.0/59493e952e1a94a95edb10d0782073a808b11dda/keen-client-java-core-5.0.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-gson/2.1.0/aa557d71ead91cbf26e0c316a0f593d168303309/converter-gson-2.1.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.stripe/stripe-java/3.5.0/1f94c8eb165e072da47469763ee74697a0acc45/stripe-java-3.5.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/751f548c85fa49f330cecbb1875893f971b33c4e/gson-2.7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-core-11.0.2.aar/1456345113dac43ee724779c29328038/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-auth-11.0.2.aar/c70c35e8ea85ce516b6c3f75081beeae/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-database-11.0.2.aar/019fc1af21f35dbcae07f3c32e51da4d/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-ads-11.0.2.aar/4f4342cdae105a0dd435afb6fdded11e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-storage-11.0.2.aar/0ce3385d91297486d9d18491fcd7bdfb/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-perf-11.0.2.aar/a1118b79fb1ab9d666cd22c04ef97fb4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-nearby-11.0.2.aar/c1352daa47f550373137c81a4d012011/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-location-11.0.2.aar/19c93a0e7b4bf3b50cdfa7bd03425fb6/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-places-11.0.2.aar/97958df271160b9519d81b9e736ebffd/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-ads-11.0.2.aar/ec8c559dacb5e77a10ef26f8af9f775f/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-wallet-11.0.2.aar/2c9885a2c6f92a87da5726ef00d9b791/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-maps-11.0.2.aar/ffb05e8c61aae5a9890121a5260c3bd4/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-messaging-11.0.2.aar/4203fd3298aebb953e7bcbdf6de1a7f1/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/geofire-android-2.1.1.aar/0730cae841e0b48759c9e73bd61703dc/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.frankiesardo/auto-parcel/0.3.1/501393158454717fef27cba8d177f32a158b8955/auto-parcel-0.3.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/fab-1.6.4.aar/7212a5bdd8292a8b6c037de62901dad0/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/library-0.1.0.aar/3b8e7bd6f4901a48a4dd7524a77dd050/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/library-1.14.5.aar/bc42266211a8af8995b53d85405aa8d1/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jakewharton.picasso/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader/1.1.0/f4f77eb62269c977c154765cd01587eda6488273/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader-1.1.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/picasso-2.6.0-SNAPSHOT.aar/cd8241d302a30d8e44f003957abe6fcd/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor/3.8.1/feab46062803513d6a8307c74b0084265855de1a/logging-interceptor-3.8.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-simplexml/2.1.0/a71c37fa341165df2c61ba93f549c4ceeb98d6c8/converter-simplexml-2.1.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-scalars/2.2.0/6303d085f1da877f8cd49ae36ffc49db2ab59f4f/converter-scalars-2.2.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.3.0/bcacde6a8ccedcc56c127403d26b76072fe6214d/retrofit-2.3.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.8.1/4d060ca3190df0eda4dc13415532a12e15ca5f11/okhttp-3.8.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/stripe-android-2.0.2.aar/c5141a307a57062e90ac3143c6ab840e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/CreditCardEntry-1.4.7.aar/6c1f2245cd13b6456abbe1db7523ae92/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/subsampling-scale-image-view-3.6.0.aar/f33292a13dc086e2c26ee39cf475d441/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/logger-1.15.aar/ba11ecde0536ba3c63baee07f741eeb2/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/butterknife-8.1.0.aar/14f95240c51be6ae0e4b30b441e1e072/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.parceler/parceler-api/1.1.5/23114b381811fd7c8e7aeeef4b845453c4a16a1d/parceler-api-1.1.5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.dagger/dagger/2.11/95037eaee68aa48021511972e9db9ba29916e1c9/dagger-2.11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/circleimageview-2.1.0.aar/ada098152b74016aebbd5531cbc53a97/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/sensey-1.5.1.aar/120dcf19c7af70566c1e6034bd06dd7c/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/leakcanary-android-no-op-1.4-beta2.aar/d9c41f6620c59ecc1efc1441ab22cacf/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/transition-26.0.0-beta2.aar/49967477f2d9b139f09ab64243b29feb/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-analytics-11.0.2.aar/b9f99b28c939c9281283c83fa42cc502/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-database-connection-11.0.2.aar/d46c72d2358a6dbaa676463838ecd09e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-analytics-impl-11.0.2.aar/0c7c1375133af1be0732ac655755c2a0/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-iid-11.0.2.aar/b3b8d37b9ff5aa5a3399308eb163af3d/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-common-11.0.2.aar/f5b64bfd58ae9fc3c3380058266cd0cc/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-storage-common-11.0.2.aar/8c5100f81e0fb83f86749ca7edcd7f91/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-clearcut-11.0.2.aar/1613c21966e70b3b40dc28c82691ca60/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-auth-11.0.1.aar/91f94c8cb7e863a526130efb6853f44d/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-ads-lite-11.0.2.aar/70739be26dd6304c5476c124e1bb42da/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-gass-11.0.2.aar/dc4ce6c2d751fea4570147371ae89ab1/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-safetynet-11.0.2.aar/3c14df4b551b9f1c3529a265b4fdd1fa/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-identity-11.0.2.aar/7669a5b00b557b38008903f58bdfa30c/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-auth-base-11.0.1.aar/f7831dc23098b7eca63174e21b2b158b/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-base-11.0.2.aar/b85f6c3ac50ec082b12279297db79f9c/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-tasks-11.0.2.aar/ff81c84f960df823ea12f5a438e69cb7/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-basement-11.0.2.aar/83390a7dea9ab6de3bab0eb0751b7ea3/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v4-26.0.0-beta2.aar/02671b0a370bbef222f758a3a6b38d94/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-fragment-26.0.0-beta2.aar/9552b19b582bc7a684288e5dda3f43b5/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-utils-26.0.0-beta2.aar/00ea0c38297044d75233565dc1264fd9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jakewharton/butterknife-annotations/8.1.0/d6854f42bfb4098d3d2358d93201307b9f1cc95d/butterknife-annotations-8.1.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/animated-vector-drawable-26.0.0-beta2.aar/52e85379769487743c9b387447d9dff9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-vector-drawable-26.0.0-beta2.aar/3e737cabee81b1671b4a105c4ad31f7e/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-ui-26.0.0-beta2.aar/29abff85aa019fc24831cef84f9324a9/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-media-compat-26.0.0-beta2.aar/d5186b266d43e0447cd462047d1ea51a/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/customtabs-25.3.1.aar/48cae1d0acef708f5eed6c876f435e45/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-26.0.0-beta2.aar/cebf7b16037936cf8f05d4a525a708e3/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.support/support-annotations/26.0.0-beta2/e5ef6e4822404221c9b03dff0d31e4810ac3fb0d/support-annotations-26.0.0-beta2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/exoplayer-r1.5.13.aar/103ac5dc77a294269ba54351d068e840/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/answers-shim-0.0.4.aar/d27c0187463e098c046954469f448d0f/jars/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.13.0/a9283170b7305c8d92d25aff02a6ab7e45d06cbe/okio-1.13.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.simpleframework/simple-xml/2.7.1/dd91fb744c2ff921407475cb29a1e3fee397d411/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-android/1.4.0/cc174c559b5177982887bf6e1b76003aebad9516/bolts-android-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-applinks/1.4.0/8ad21bf21784dacce5f2043afb97218cc377e835/bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-tasks/1.4.0/d85884acf6810a3bbbecb587f239005cbc846dc4/bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/devroot/github.com/augerlabs/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/custom/debug --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/devroot/github.com/augerlabs/android/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/customDebug --classpath_entry /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/5025422767732a1ab45d93abfea846513d742dcf/jsr250-api-1.0.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/jooreill/Library/Android/sdk_2.2/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/jooreill/Library/Android/sdk_2.2/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 17 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
```

Seems to be somehow related to use of following in `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Looks like this is related to use of Play Services v11.0.2.  If I revert to 11.0.1 then I don't see this issue

**UPDATE** (July 18th):
Still seeing this issue with Canary 7

**UPDATE** (July 25th):
Still seeing this issue with Canary 8 (again when using Play Services v11.0.2 ....ok with 11.0.1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, turns out this issue was due to mismatch between play services/support library versions my app was depending on directly and transitive dependences from `FirebaseUI` - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies

Comment: Same problem but related to another third-party lib (AppsFlyer) having dependency mismatch with the application version.

Comment: Yes, this is the built-in flaw with these byte code manipulation libs, they are not robust, and in fact very brittle and delicate. It's always seemed to me they threw out all good OO practices and we are back to tightly-wired programming constructs. Much has already been written about this, but the woeful developer that has to deal with this doesn't have much say in the matter as it is higher up the chain. I'd be curious about a monetary figure for amount wasted solving byte code errors. Signed: just a woeful developer bitten by his share of these annoying bugs when there are better ways.

Answer (score 22):

I had that issue when moved to Android Studio 3.0

Ensure that you have **same versions of firebase-core and play-services**, e.g.:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 20):

With Android Studio 3.1, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0` and `gradle-4.4-all.zip` this issue resolving with adding

> **android.enableD8.desugaring = true**

in gradle.properties file.

Comment: compiling with gradle from CLI works but android studio reports problem when trying to synchronize gradle with project - WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'. Android studio 3.3.2

Answer (score 18):

For those who encounter this problem on an ionic or cordova project this command will help you:

`cordova clean android`

Comment: Thanks. It was a quick fix

Comment: this fixed my problem

Answer (score 8):

For me, it happened with AS3.0 stable, with classfiles from previous beta version. The solution was to do a `Build -> Clean Project`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2384#issuecomment-376793947 ?

Try adding `android.enableD8.desugaring = true` in gradle.properties and you may need to add proguard rule `-dontwarn java.lang.invoke**`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a gradle bug. 
Just update your gradle (/gradle/wapper/gradle-wapper.properties) manually and try build again to find more helpful infomation.

---

Here is how I solved my problem as this may be helpful.

I'm using AndroidStudio 3.0.1 with embedded gradle 4.1-all (Newly installed), and a project which worked fine yesterday.

I guess it's a Gradle problem so I upgraded my Gradle wapper manually to 4.4.1-all (2017/12/29, the last release version in http://services.gradle.org/distributions/), then cleaned and built again.

Sadly, this exception appeared again, but with more information:

```
Error:注: [1] Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: []
警告: C:\Users\23256\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jooq\joor\0.9.7\dab4ea4a43112773b593c898df9fbfb19c42ac3b\joor-0.9.7.jar(org/joor/Reflect.class): 主版本 53 比 52 新, 此编译器支持最新的主版本。
建议升级此编译器。
警告: C:\Users\23256\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jooq\joor\0.9.7\dab4ea4a43112773b593c898df9fbfb19c42ac3b\joor-0.9.7.jar(org/joor/ReflectException.class): 主版本 53 比 52 新, 此编译器支持最新的主版本。
建议升级此编译器。
注: 某些输入文件使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。
注: 有关详细信息, 请使用 -Xlint:deprecation 重新编译。
2 个警告
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.CoreLibraryRewriter.reader(CoreLibraryRewriter.java:44)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:388)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments...
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

This message helped me to fix the problem: I'm using jooR in my project, and it told me something's wrong with it, so I checked http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=joor, found it has split into 2 projects, so I replaced my dependencies like this:

```
-    //https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.jooq%3Ajoor
-    //https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR
-    api 'org.jooq:joor:0.9.7'
+    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/joor-java-8
+    api group: 'org.jooq', name: 'joor-java-8', version: '0.9.7'
```

Clean and build, and it now passes.