# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'. --classpath_entry

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2
Build #AI-171.4263559, built on August 11, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3
```

Gradle File

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile project(':libs:scanlibrary')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:$googlePlayVersion"
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    /*LeakCanary Lib*/

    /*debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
                    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
                    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'*/
    compile 'org.immutables:gson:2.5.3'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"

    /*compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'*/
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'

    //compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    //09062017 AppController , StethoDebugLib , LeakCanaryApplication , OkHttpStack
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'

    //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    // We need to change this lib because it is depricated

    //volley Library is updated
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'

    // Newer version
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta.1'

    //compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.6.1'

    //04082017

    //compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta.1'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.11'
    //testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestUtil 'com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-app:1.3.0@apk'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    //compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')

    //compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')

    //compile files('libs/curvesapi-1.04.jar')

    //compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi

    //  compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17-beta1'

    //compile files('libs/poi-3.15.jar')

    //compile files('libs/poi-excelant-3.15-beta2.jar')

    //compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.15.jar')

    //compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta1.jar')

    //compile files('libs/poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar')

    //compile files('libs/lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
        compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.15'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas
        compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.15'
        compile(group: 'org.apache.poi', name : 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15') {
            exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        }
}
```

---

```
> Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating
> feature. useNewCruncher has been deprecated. It will be removed in a
> future version of the gradle plugin. New cruncher is now always
> enabled. Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
> 'implementation' instead. Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in
> project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
> registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is
> deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) Configuration
> 'compile' in project ':libs:scanlibrary' is deprecated. Use
> 'implementation' instead. :app:preBuild :libs:scanlibrary:preBuild
> :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :libs:scanlibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResValues :libs:scanlibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:checkDebugManifest :app:processDebugGoogleServices
> Parsing json file: F:\DocNest\app\google-services.json
> :libs:scanlibrary:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:compileDebugAidl :app:preDebugBuild
> :libs:scanlibrary:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> :libs:scanlibrary:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:processDebugResources :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript
> UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
> :libs:scanlibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:generateDebugSources
> :libs:scanlibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> :libs:scanlibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
> UP-TO-DATE :libs:scanlibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
> :libs:scanlibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
> UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
> UP-TO-DATE
> :libs:scanlibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugManifest :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:processDebugResources :app:generateDebugSources
> :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE :app:compileDebugSources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:extractTryWithResourcesSupportJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expect only the fields in this
> interface to be initialized.
> owner=org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/xb/ltgfmt/Code$1,
> expected=org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/xb/ltgfmt/Code
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:721)
>         at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring$InterfaceFieldWriteCollector.visitFieldInsn(InterfaceDesugaring.java:260)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitFieldInsn(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.tree.FieldInsnNode.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:383)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>         at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
>         at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
>         at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
>         at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\29e80d2dd51f9dcdef8f9ffaee0d4dc1c9bbfc87\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar --output F:\DocNest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\75.jar --classpath_entry F:\DocNest\app\libs\activation.jar --classpath_entry F:\DocNest\app\libs\additionnal.jar --classpath_entry F:\DocNest\app\libs\mail.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-auth-11.2.0.aar\8401935c7d741c4cead90c1451e96f7e\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-core-11.2.0.aar\2ccfc9ece186a56ca5668f64b81c49ee\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-config-11.2.0.aar\236ea95d8065013b788c89834b60f91f\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-storage-11.2.0.aar\7e44d431a5931e1a1bc52cca2aa3e742\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-11.2.0.aar\1b7b5731604475bc550e4054b9da677e\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-crash-11.2.0.aar\afaa9afaa3b1e3b9709e8ca8ca7f199d\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-location-11.2.0.aar\bbdf86781dd9c6c52a1e4d71b0f0b6d3\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-maps-11.2.0.aar\a2bc1edd2cf60cbd6fdc54430d35c73d\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-messaging-11.2.0.aar\51e74511dc746363050043680e7017ad\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-drive-11.2.0.aar\5e200230e9a7e5a6bf1114121fdecdcc\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.api-client\google-api-client-android\1.20.0\5673179575c32b69a474334255c3044adf18d40\google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.immutables\gson\2.5.3\cda5940af521def2e9732a5e05a1b6cea1277e47\gson-2.5.3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-26.0.1.aar\c326ee7c9d8cdb0d1fc063dbe1b80195\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\recyclerview-v7-26.0.1.aar\b8dc83888df5515da8b3a185cce57e04\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0.aar\b8516c51009b5ded2d9fd59b76fd92d6\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\cardview-v7-26.0.1.aar\e8512f13fbd486879425b2ab90ebde4c\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\multidex-1.0.2.aar\217c484acc28c0d163bacd4563114968\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.stetho\stetho-okhttp\1.3.1\74fc68939b8668d18ce02c16f33e1f60f4d2befe\stetho-okhttp-1.3.1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\stetho-1.5.0.aar\ffda44b30cd3298d9bea1752dc9c52ce\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp\okhttp\2.7.2\20f6463eb19ac61960c5d91a094c2f4f0727dc2e\okhttp-2.7.2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\volley-1.0.0.aar\9fbe4431e743148e1f87a62c5b38eee9\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.0.2.aar\e6bb4cfc22fcbd377b8886ca946479a1\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.aar\73bb827ed757f972cd6302fa4b6bd652\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\android-pdf-viewer-2.7.0-beta.1.aar\accbe54826b62a1c6edff3a858b0e8f8\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.itextpdf\itextpdf\5.5.11\4c66347f10e9dbf062a086e1223a0d0a9eeb3677\itextpdf-5.5.11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.poi\poi-ooxml\3.15\e2800856735b07b8edd417aee07685470216a00f\poi-ooxml-3.15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.poi\poi\3.15\965bba8899988008bb2341e300347de62aad5391\poi-3.15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.15\de4a50ca39de48a19606b35644ecadb2f733c479\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-api-phone-11.2.0.aar\6d3b85c527dfc4ac7f2bf4d574ebf222\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-auth-base-11.2.0.aar\0b133186192e742efe8d49a70b538e75\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.2.0.aar\82b7408d0dfcabd764e019ddb3938940\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-analytics-11.2.0.aar\1c9a64718a8fa39d4da24de9e2dc30b5\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-analytics-impl-11.2.0.aar\9c53b7b6f61b2a42623c59b38977ba30\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-iid-11.2.0.aar\922a40cdc81a25da8ee7f3a952fbf11a\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-common-11.2.0.aar\d9508e22b830a4124b5b1adeaa5c4c72\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-tasks-11.2.0.aar\521a9c6f883414456cb8f986c7a3b7db\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-storage-common-11.2.0.aar\bcb0525fb11a286c91ecb3a6c7497126\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-basement-11.2.0.aar\2d737e7d061fa5ac15fbbddff39c4826\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\pdfium-android-1.7.0.aar\ed1581b418a42a41df7c41bed8936190\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\transition-26.0.1.aar\b3880a7d2819b90140230707ca84c06f\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\easypermissions-0.1.9.aar\996f70dd9246298a7ea890bfc06455d1\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.1.aar\023b495758677157859ec098d57e5706\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-v4-26.0.1.aar\dd61c7d70c7f5df25d67ca190a41a47c\jars\classes.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.bumptech.glide\glide\3.7.0\9e9eeaf9948ee4d6c3ab354e8dc14368f16994a4\glide-3.7.0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.api-client\google-api-client\1.20.0\d3e66209ae9e749b2d6833761e7885f60f285564\google-api-client-tasks\1.4.0\d85884acf6810a3bbbecb587f239005cbc846dc4\bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\49c100caf72d658aca8e58bd74a4ba90fa2b0d70\stax-api-1.0.1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\user11\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.1.3\f6c3aed1cdfa21b5c1737c915186ea93a95a58bd\jackson-core-2.1.3.jar --classpath_entry F:\DocNest\libs\scanlibrary\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar --classpath_entry F:\DocNest\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --bootclasspath_entry D:\android-sdks\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry D:\android-sdks\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform.lambda$processNonCachedOnes$3(DesugarTransform.java:324)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 1 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

38 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 33 up-to-date
```

Comment: `org/apache/xmlbeans`... Something is wrong with that library. Regardless of the fact that it is commented **all JAR files** are picked up by `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: Looks like a duplicated question, please check this link to see if your problem is related to play-services and firebase version mismatch:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127162/transformclasseswithdesugar-build-error-after-updating-to-as-3-0-canary-6