# Desugar Error after updating gradle to 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments** {--input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/76.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/77.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/47.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/45.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/42.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/66.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/67.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/60.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/61.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/26.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/39.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/46.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/35.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/53.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/54.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/18.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/83.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/84.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/61.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/62.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/80.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/81.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/67.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/68.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/21.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/12.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/8.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/23.jar --input /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --output /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/50.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/51.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/52.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/53.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/54.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/55.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/56.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/57.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/58.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/59.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/60.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/61.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/62.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/63.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/64.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/65.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/66.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/67.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/68.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/69.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/70.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/71.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/72.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/73.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/74.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/75.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/76.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/77.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/78.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/79.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/80.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/81.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/82.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/83.jar --classpath_entry /root/AndroidStudioProjects/HeallifyDoctors/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/84.jar --bootclasspath_entry /root/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /root/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

I got this after update gradle to 3.0.1

I applied various solutions but didn't worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? I am facing the same issue and also research and try a lot of solution but still not work.

Comment: yes I solved that problem, I guess some libraries in my project creating created those problems. 
So I  made one new project and copied all file from previous one to new project directory. 
If your gradle version is above 3 then include java 8 support in app. @KhangTran

Comment: it's fixed, check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49894977/1778343