# Fix "Couldn't desugar invokedynamic" when running androidConnectedTest

Tags: android, lambda, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

My Android app uses Java 8 lambdas like so:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(view -> someMethod());
```

Everything works fine with the above when building the app or running unit tests. However, when I run `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':myModule:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebugAndroidTest'.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't desugar invokedynamic for com/.../MyActivity.onClick using java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; (6) with arguments [(Landroid/view/View;)V, com/.../MyActivity.lambda$onViewBound$0(Landroid/view/View;)V (7), (Landroid/view/View;)V]
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:474)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no such method: com...MyActivity.lambda$onViewBound$0(View)void/invokeSpecial
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:867)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1003)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1386)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findSpecial(MethodHandles.java:1004)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.toMethodHandle(LambdaDesugaring.java:670)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.toJvmMetatype(LambdaDesugaring.java:647)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:408)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/.../databinding/MyActivityBinding
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com...databinding.MyActivityBinding not found
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

Note that removing the lambda makes it build again. Any idea on what could be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: 1. Please make sure that all sub-modules use the same android plugin version and gradle version ; 
2. With Android Studio 3.1, com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 and gradle-4.4-all.zip this issue resolving with adding **android.enableD8.desugaring = true** in **gradle.properties** file. ; reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127162/transformclasseswithdesugar-build-error-after-updating-to-as-3-0-canary-6/49894977#49894977

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, problem was using of wrong dependency in classpath used in gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.cryptonode.jncryptor:jncryptor:1.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        // The following adds the ability to use @DebugLog on methods
        // instead on 1.2.1 I was using 1.1.0 which was the problem
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}
```